# Normal Map Baking edge problem

Tags: normal-map, tilesize

I tried to bake my normal map tile but it didn't give me any result

[image]

When I add the bevel to the tile giving me this normal map but my tile don't have this smooth edge it's a hard edge any advice about it.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normal bake saves the faces orientation. The bake won't happen if the rays meet orthogonal or frontal normals, it will only work if the normals are tilted. Here in picture 1 the faces won't be baked, but in picture 2 the ones that are tilted will be:

[image]